# Binding or simplying a .net DataSet through nusoap

Tags: .net, dataset, nusoap

I am using nusoap to consume web services provided by a .net application which fetches data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The "middleware" web service is being written for me to provide business-oriented web services rather than direct access to the underlying data structures.

Many of the web services are providing structured data in the form of DataSets. These all look good in the Microsoft world where they can be bound to tables and other user elements and *just work*.

However, my problem is that consuming these DataSet objects through the SOAP interface gives me some pretty complex structures (arrays nested many levels deep) output from nusoap. Is there a PHP library that will help me make sense of those structures? In the end I just want the raw data in simple PHP structures (i.e. simple structured associative arrays) and don't want to start guessing what I need to pull from these DataSet structures.

Sorry this is a little vague - I am really looking for what I may be overlooking in interpreting these complex data structures sent through SOAP by the .net application using PHP nusoap as the client - a nudge in the right direction perhaps.

Edited:

In case it helps, the nested arrays I am getting back include "diffgram" data, something which I am not yet familiar with. It seems that a diffgram is a "standard" MS format to represent sets of data, but does present me with a very complex array structure to try and parse. Perhaps there is a PHP library to handle diffgrams?

Comment: I think I just need to understand the structure of a diffgram as spat out by nusoap. It seems to be fairly consistent in structure, with a list of records at $result['GetFooBarsResult']['diffgram']['DocumentElement']['Foo'][0..n]... This post gives me some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587911/how-to-retreive-the-values-using-php-variable-array-nusoap

Answer (score 1):

I think I have my answer now, at least something that works for now.

The .Net web service functions are all returning a single DataSet, containing multiple tables. This is returned by nusoap in a consistent way:

```
array(
    'ResultSetName => array(
        'schema' => array(...),
        'diffgram' => array(
            'DataSetName' => array(
                'Table1NameWithOneRow' => array(
                    'Column1' => 'Value1',
                    'Column2' => 'Value2',
                    ...
                ),
                'Table2NameWithManyRows' => array(
                    0 => array(
                       'Column1' => 'Value1',
                       'Column2' => 'Value2',
                       ...
                    ),
                    1 => array(
                       'Column1' => 'Value1',
                       'Column2' => 'Value2',
                       ...
                    ),
                    ...
                ),
                ...
            )
        )
)
```

This is easy enough to parse: throw away the ResultSetName to leave the schema and diffgram. Throw away the schema to leave just the diffgram. Take just the first element of the diffgram (throw away anything but the first DataSet). Throw away the DataSetName. These leaves me with the array of tables.

Now, if just one row is returned in a table, the data is one level higher, i.e. does not appear in an array of element 0, as the first row in a *two* row table would, so that needs to be accounted for. Otherwise I just scan the table data and throw away any elements with a key that starts with an "!", as that is some kind of metadata.

This then leaves me with raw data in nested arrays, which is what I pass on for further processing in my PHP scripts.

Things to watch out for include tables with zero rows which are simply not sent at all - not even an empty array. Dates can easily be recognised and parsed automatically, otherwise it is up to the consuming process to do what it likes with the data.

It would be nice to have this parsing in a "diffgram" library that understands a lot more about the diffgram structure than I do. I hope this is useful to someone.